# Enum with Many Parameters

Tags: java, parameters, enums, dry, builder

What's the best way to avoid long lists of parameters in an Enum?  Is there an Enum equivalent of the builder pattern?  I'm trying to avoid having to switch over the Enum values because that would violate the DRY principle.

As you can see below, it can be difficult to keep track of more than a few parameters:

```
public enum ExmapleEnum {
    FOO(20, 75, 100),
    BAR(41, 6, 240),
    BAZ(2, 19, 80);

    private int mAge;
    private int mHeight;
    private int mWeight;

    private ExmapleEnum(int age, int height, int weight) {
        mAge = age;
        mHeight = height;
        mWeight = weight;
    }

    // Remainder omitted...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
public enum ExampleEnum {
    FOO(InitParams.builder()
                  .setAge(20)
                  .build()),
    ...

    private ExampleEnum(InitParams params) {
        ...
    }

    private static class InitParams {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you can either populate the fields based on the built `InitParams` or you can store the `InitParams` object as a field.